# how to group facet.field in solr

Tags: solr, facet

I am trying to get the count of two fields grouped together in solr. exactly as we do in mysql

```
select count(*), F1, F2 from MyTable where F3='X' group by F1,F2
```

when we try facet query and facet field like below

```
http://localhost:8888/solr/myCore/select?q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=F1&facet.field=F2&wt=xml&fq=F3:X&version=2.2&rows=1
```

but this gives the count for each field separately. Anybody knows how to get the desired grouping? what should the link above be to get the correct grouping?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When indexing make a new field that has both F1 and F2 in the same field (like F1-F2) and facet on that.

Answer (score 0):

facet.field would give you different facet count each for each facet.field resp.
If you want to group for facets, you probably need to create a new field with the combined content. e.g. `f1_f2` which would have f1 value append to f2

e.g.
F1 = Aero
F2 = Space
F1_F2=Aero_Space  (This field needs to be created at index time at client side.)

Comment: could you please advise how to do so? do you mean be creating sub-query? or there is another way to do so?

Comment: you would need to do it at index time. Create a new field f1_f2 and have the content appended to each other and use the new field for facet or grouping.